# How to order pages wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was using the plugin [My Page Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-page-order/) to order my pages, I then turned off all my plugins and then turned them back on but now its not working anymore. Does any one know how to order pages in wordpress?

Heres the url
http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/rugs/animals/

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score 1):

There is already a way to do that when you edit pages in wordpress. Take a look at this [image](http://cdn.tentblogger.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/wordpress-screen-options-add-new-page.png).In the bottom right hand corner you'll see a box that says "order" with a zero in it. You can change that number to whatever you want and the pages will sort by that number ascending order.

You should also take a look at the files in your theme and locate the [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) function that is used to render the menu you're looking at. That function takes a 'sort_column' argument that can override your menu order. Removing / modifying that argument will help you.

Comment: Perhaps in the place you're looking, the order is set in the theme file itself. Do you know how to view files in your theme to locate the wp_list_pages() function? That function takes a 'sort_column' argument that can override your menu order. Updated my answer.